# Multiple Rows Update with same form names in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting caught up on PHP again, and have the following update code. This works, but only for the last one inserted? I need to update for all gritem id's. I thought adding the [] to a form field that is not unique allows PHP to parse it as an array, but it still sees it as one field?

My HTML I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="gritemid[]" value="<?PHP echo $row2['gritemid']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="grqty[]" id="grqty[]" value=""  />
```

The Following PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['storageloc']))
{
    //Set the GRQTY to subtract from the Orderqty on each item in the list if selected
    // find out how many records there are to update
    $size = count($_POST['gritemid']);

    // start a loop in order to update each record
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $size) {
        // define each variable
        $gritemid= $_POST['gritemid'][$i];
        $grqty= $_POST['grqty'][$i];
        if ($grqty > "0") {
            // do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback
            $query = "UPDATE gr_items SET orderqty = orderqty - $grqty WHERE gritemid = '$gritemid' LIMIT 1";
            mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
        }
        ++$i;
    }
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: Start by doing a print_r($_POST) to see what you are getting.  Not seeing any obvious errors.  The id="grqty[]" needs to go away since id's should be unique.  But it should not be causing any harm unless you have some javascript going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you really should do some validation/sanitisation of your post vars before dropping them into a query. As both the vars you are using appear to be integers I would suggest using `intval()` -

```
// define each variable
$gritemid = intval($_POST['gritemid'][$i]);
$grqty = intval($_POST['grqty'][$i]);
```

If you replace your call to mysql_query() with `print($query);` do you see the multiple queries that you would expect?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, not sure why the difference was just adding intval? Im guessing the other was seen as a string and thus ignored?